# Specifying options to underlying `Integrate` when using `NExpectation`

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

I'm computing the max over a set of uniformly distributed random variables. I know that this value converges to 1 as the number of variables increases. Mathematica is having difficulty computing the approximation for larger values of `n`:

```
ListPlot[
 Table[NExpectation[Max @@ Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[], {i, 1, n}]], {n, 
   1, 10}]]
```

Notice that the approximation is near 0 for one of the points, and I get several warnings:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is it possible to fix?

It looks like it could be related to the option `MaxPiecewiseCases`, but I can't seem to specify that from the call to `NExpectation`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `OrderDistribution` makes it easy:

```
Mean[OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n}, n]]
(* n/(1 + n) *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Use the [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) of the [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html)

```
data = Table[
  Mean[
   TransformedDistribution[Max @@ Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}],
    Table[x[i] \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[], {i, 1, n}]]],
  {n, 1, 10}]

(* {1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 6/7, 7/8, 8/9, 9/10, 10/11} *)

ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

For arbitrary `n`

```
mean[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[data, n]

(* n/(1 + n) *)
```

**EDIT:** Using [`NExpectation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html)

```
data2 = Table[
  NExpectation[Max @@ Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}],
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[], {i, 1, n}],
   WorkingPrecision -> 15,
   Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "SamplingIncrement" -> 10^6}],
  {n, 1, 10}]

(* {0.499634476170700, 0.666505623364029, 0.751636048372117, \
0.798185580996715, 0.834673695845299, 0.858042194869023, \
0.872491243043538, 0.885804474685710, 0.898368121403151, \
0.912293708632319} *)

ListPlot[data2]
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea why this works but my example doesnt? It seems like they should be implemented the same way.